# Simple WordPress "wp_head" Action Hook

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

having a problem which is driving me crazy, reason being that it should be a really simple fix, basically in my "footer.php" file I need some lines of CSS added to the "wp_head" hook. What I expected to work was this:

```
<?php function footer_widgets() { ?>
<style type="text/css">
#footer {
    border-top:0 !important;
    margin-top:0 !important;
    padding-top:0 !important;
}
</style>
<?php } add_action('wp_head', 'footer_widgets');?>
```

This does nothing, the weird thing is if I change the hook from "wp_head" to "wp_footer" it outputs to that hook fine, but this **needs** to be in "wp_head".

If anyone has any idea how to solve this it would be much appreciated.
Cheers,
Tom.

Comment: Is there any reason this code needs to be in your footer.php? If you put it into your functions.php file it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

On a normal page, your footer.php isn't included until after `wp_head` has already run. See that `get_footer()` in your template? That's when this code runs. You need to include this code in a file that is loaded earlier in the page lifecycle (e.g. functions.php).

Comment: Ahh, my bad, at the time my mind was blanked, cheers for that!